# OPC UA - opcua milo eclipse - reconnection, manual creation of connection, subscription to structure (object)

Tags: java, subscription, opc-ua, milo

I am student working on my thesis where I need OPC UA connection. I spent almost week to trying to solve this on my own but without success, so I would like to ask few things and I would be so glad if someone could help me.

**1) Subscription to structure (object with fields)**
I need to subscribe to object which includes two arrays (representing curve) so there is array with x coordinates and array with y coordinates but I have no idea how to do it. I am able to subscribe to them separately but not to whole structure.

**2) Is there possibility how to subscribe  not using discovery of endpoints?**
Why I am asking is that I would like to create connection by my own so even thought the OPC UA server is not running at the moment my app would connect to it when it become available. This is not possible when I use discovery of endpoints because it is not running. But I think the milo should handle the reconnection if I create the endpoint by hand or am I wrong?

Jakub Znamenáček

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You just subscribe to the NodeId of the Variable with a structured value. You'll have to make sure the DataTypeDictionary is being read by the client on startup. See [this example](https://github.com/eclipse/milo/blob/e854374845e6c5f46a7b033c2c62cee2ee10622a/milo-examples/client-examples/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/examples/client/UnifiedAutomationReadCustomDataTypeExample.java#L43-L48). If the server is properly exposing the structure definition in a datatype dictionary there shouldn't be much else required.
2. You are responsible for retrying until you have an EndpointDescription. Once you have an endpoint and you've created an `OpcUaClient` instance it will connect and keep reconnecting after the first time you call `connect()` but you have to get the endpoint and configure the client yourself.

Comment: 1) Thank you for reply I will go trough that example 2) I know about that but when I know the ip address of the server and so on I can not create endpoint manually? Because would not like to write some cycle checking for the EndpointDescription.

Comment: 1) Ok, I went trough the code and if I am right the ExtensionObject is holding the data and than I need to decode them. For that is .decode() method I guess. Then I get little bit confused. I think that in  client.getSerializationContext() is included the DataTypeManager but I have no idea where. Would it be possible if someone could give me step by step guide (not necessary code, but I would appreciate it) how to do it. I mean something like -> create this and that because you will use it for that

Comment: Until you've connected to the server at least once you don't have all the information you might need to create an EndpointDescription, e.g. you don't have the server's certificate.

Comment: Thanks so much for fast reply, is this also true when I am trying to connect insecurely?

Comment: You also don't have the ApplicationDescription containing the server URI and other information. Stop swimming upstream, write a loop that tries to connect until you can choose an endpoint to configure the client with.

Comment: Ok thank you, I just wanted to be 100% sure that I am doing it right. Do you have any suggestion how often should i check for connection. I don't know how big problem is if I will check for example every 5s because what can happen is that the server will not be connected for one month or more.

Comment: Regarding the automatic reconnection I am getting this log after reconnection. Do you know what it means `Notifying 1 java.io.IOException: Operation timed out`, `Unable to transfer subscription, resubscribing to NodeId{ns=3, id="PrServo_EdgeExchange"."runtimeData"."trends"."updateHmiTrend"} `, `Notifying 1 ServiceFaultListeners`. I know it is tough with me ...

Comment: The log message is something you must have written, it's not part of Milo. It sounds like on reconnect the subscription transfer is failing for some reason but it's not clear from the message here why. It might help to get a Wireshark capture of this happening. You should also consider moving this conversation to the milo-dev mailing list instead of the comments here.

Comment: Thanks, I will do so, just to be sure, do you mean milo-dev@eclipse.org?